# Catch Email and Its Attachments PHP

Tags: php, email

What I am trying to do is, lets say, our users send an email to help@supportmysite.com, then as soon as help@supportmysite.com receives an email, it checks the parts of the email and gets the title, email from whom we got the mail, text body, and the attachments in it.

How can i go about making  a system like that in PHP? This is my first time developing something like this. I haven't really ever fiddled with PHP mailer and other stuff related to mails, so need a little help :)

Thanks :D

Comment: Depends entirely on your mail delivery infrastructure. For a local mailbox, look at Procmail. For IMAP or POP, there is a PHP library (see @Rick's answer).

Comment: Lets say the mailbox is the one used in Cpanel(like support@yoursite.com). Then, I should go for IMAP right?

Comment: This reveals nothing about how you access the mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PHP IMAP documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) It can be used to retrieve various bits of information from emails so I think that'd be a good starting point for you.